# panic: Failed to load dbcapi.dll:

Tags: c++, windows, go, gcc, dll

I have an error when building a Golang project

> panic: Failed to load dbcapi.dll: The specified module could not be
>   found.
>
> ```
> goroutine 1 [running]:
> syscall.MustLoadDLL(0x8603bb, 0xa, 0x1)
>   C:/Go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:77 +0x76
>
> Process finished with exit code 2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

May be some help there :

https://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/esignal/standard-esignal-api/dbcapi-dll/

You probably have to download the .dll and set it to the right path.

EDIT:

The first proposition of the link above is to following this steps :

> When you install software that uses the dbcapi.dll dependency, the
>   software should automatically register the file for you. In some cases
>   your DLL file may not register properly, and as a result, will provide
>   a "dbcapi.dll not registered" error. Fortunately, you can use a
>   built-in utility called "Microsoft Register Server" (regsvr32.exe) to
>   re-register your dbcapi.dll file.
>
> How to re-register dbcapi.dll from an elevated command prompt (Windows
>   XP, Vista, 7, 8, and 10):
>
> 1. Click the Start button.
> 2. Type "command" in the search box... DO NOT hit ENTER yet!
> 3. While holding CTRL-Shift on your keyboard, hit ENTER.
> 4. You will be prompted with a permission dialog box.
> 5. Click Yes
> 6. Type the following command: regsvr32 /u dbcapi.dll
> 7. Hit ENTER. This will UN-REGISTER your file
> 8. Type the following command: regsvr32 /i dbcapi.dll.
> 9. Hit ENTER. This will RE-REGISTER your file
> 10. Close the command prompt window
> 11. Re-start the program associated with dbcapi.dll error.

Can't copy-past all the other solutions, it will be too long, so try it first.

Comment: Please provide a solution instead of links as the answer becomes irrelevant when the link is dead.